# Forcing word wrap - keeping "code" style inline with text box

Tags: css, word-wrap

I am using a feed aggregating website.  Sometimes I get post such as this:
http://www.r-bloggers.com/network-visualization-in-r-with-the-igraph-package/

Where the code-text overflows the text-box of the post.  Here is a screen shot:

[image]

Is there a way to make sure in the css of the site that this overflow does not happen?

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried to add css to the code tag?

Comment: The text is wrapping already for me using Chrome 24.0.1312.2 dev-m. In which browser(s) are you seeing the un-wrapped text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HI now used to this  **define** your `pre` tag `white-space: pre-wrap;`

as like this

```
pre {
white-space: pre-wrap;      /* CSS3 */   
   white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Firefox */    
   white-space: -pre-wrap;     /* Opera <7 */   
   white-space: -o-pre-wrap;   /* Opera 7 */    
   word-wrap: break-word;      /* IE */
}
```

***[more info](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/whitespace/)***

**The result is** [image]

Comment: Using `word-wrap: break-word` is questionable, because it breaks code words too – it could break “foobar” to “fooba” and “r”. It’s probably better to let the content overflow (or cause scrolling) on IE 7 and older.